# Future.get cannot block the thread in forkjoinpool/workstealingpool

Tags: java, concurrency, block, future, forkjoinpool

I set the size of workstealingpool as 1. It seems that the future.get() doesn't block the thread.

```
@Test
public void runAsyncThenApplyExample() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(1);
    CompletableFuture cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> {
                //assertTrue(Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
                System.out.println("func: " + threadName());
                Callable<Long> callable = () ->stub();
                Future<Long> future = executor.submit(callable);
                try {
                    future.get();  <<<<< **I think this should block the thread**
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return 1;
            }, executor).thenAccept(s -> {
        System.out.println("accept: " + threadName());
    });
    //assertFalse(cf.isDone());
    System.out.println("main: " + threadName());
    sleep(10);
    assertTrue(cf.isDone());
}

private Long stub() {
    System.out.println("stub: " + threadName());
    return 1L;
}
private String threadName() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getName();
}
```

output:

> func: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3
>   main: main
>   stub: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3
>   accept: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3

It seems that Future.get() and stub are using the same threead.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, it blocks until your `stub` returns, but that is super-fast, so you won't notice it.

Comment: If it blocks, why the get thread is the same as the stub thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Executors.newWorkStealingPool(1);` uses `ForkJoinPool` which has an undocumented feature called compensation threads.

From http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html (emphasis mine):

> Introduced with JDK1.8 is the CompletableFuture Class. To quote the JavaDoc:
>
> “A Future that may be explicitly completed (setting its value and status), and may include dependent functions and actions that trigger upon its completion.”
>
> **Not mentioned in the JavaDoc is that when using a large number of dependent functions with a get() method, the framework creates “compensation threads”** to continue fetching application tasks from the deques and submission queue.

So when you do `future.get();` it blocks but another thread is created in which the task is executed.

When running your code the output I'm getting is:

> func: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
>   main: main
>   stub: ForkJoinPool-1-**worker-0**
>   accept: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1

You haven't showed your `threadName()` method maybe there is a mistake in it and because of that you're seeing the same thread name (or you use different JVM which uses the same name in such case, check the thread ID)? If not please provide full code which outputs func and stub as the same threads.

Comment: I just added my threadName() function. In my case, it seems that the function get() is blocked but the thread is not blocked while using "WorkStealing/ForkJoinPool". If I use "newFixedThreadPool" and set size to 1, both the function and the thread are blocked

Comment: For the "compensation threads", if it shows some new thread names, it makes sense. In my env, it always shows the same thread, which make me puzzled.

Comment: I dumped the thread and it seems that Future.get() and stub are using the same thread.

Comment: @zero With `newFixedThreadPool(1)` you just have one normal thread, submitting new task to it from a running task and waiting for the new task to end will obviously block, that behaves as expected. On your system your code does indeed use one thread, what JDK are you using? I tested it on JDK 8, looks like Oracle improved the ForkJoin framework and on your system it's smart enough to reuse the same thread for the `stub` task.

Comment: It looks like OpenJDK 11 is smart enough to reuse the same thread. So, I think Future.get() is a block function, it only blocks some sort of "Task" but not block the current thread.  If I change the "WorkStealingPool/ForkJoinPool" to some other thread pool, such as FixedThreadPool, Future.get() will block both function and current thread.

Comment: @zero Yes, exactly. ForkJoin is a framework to run tasks on top of Java Threads. Like you said, blocking a task doesn't mean the actual Java thread has to be blocked.

Answer (score -1):

Future.get() blocks, it means that the code following the Future.get() will not be executed until the Result is obtained. Even in your output you can see stub finishes execution first. Can you try putting a sleep of 5 mins or so  in your stub before your return statement and see what happens?

Comment: It seems that the function get() is blocked but the thread is not blocked.  If I use "newFixedThreadPool" and set size to 1,  both the function and the thread are blocked